# Images not displaying in word File after linking images in the file

Tags: image, hyperlink, ms-word

I have a word file.

I have inserted images by linking it to avoid more size of doc file. Here I have kept the all images into a folder and linked in the doc file. This works fine.

But, when I send to my friend the doc file the the image file, the images cannot be seen. Quite obvious due to path has been changed.

I don't want to host the images online. If I do, this will resolve if I'm online.

If I'm off line I can't view the images in the doc file.

How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get your friend to edit hyperlinks to update it to location of each image on their machine?

Comment: you could host the images online for your friend to view but keep a local copy on your own machine so that you can still view them when offline. If you host on Google Drive it is possible to view offline as well